# Regex not returning specific match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract a link from a script tag on a website.
currently my regex returns the whole block for some reason..

This is the content of the script tag I want to get the link from:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var key = '';
var url = 'http://stream1.song365.me/h1/20160129/1772422101/The%20Beatles%20-%20There%27s%20a%20Place%20%28Studio%20Outtake%20Takes%205%20%26%206%29_(song365.cc).mp3';
var hqurl = 'http://stream1.song365.me/h1/20160129/1772422101/The%20Beatles%20-%20There%27s%20a%20Place%20%28Studio%20Outtake%20Takes%205%20%26%206%29_(song365.cc).mp3';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[rel='digg']").click(function(){
        var method = $(this).attr("method");
        var v = parseInt($(this).find('em').html());
        var p = this;
        $.post("/track/digg/2788951/" + method, function(data){
            if(data.status==0)
            {
                alert("today you have been digg it!")
            }
            else
            {
                $(p).find('em').html(data.number);
            }
        }, "JSON")
    })
    if(url.length!=0)
    {
        $("#download-link").attr("href", url + "?key=" + key).css("display","");;
    }
    if(hqurl.length!=0)
    {
        $("#download-link-hq").attr("href", hqurl + "?key=" + key).css("display","");
    }
});
</script>
```

This is the code I currently have:

```
request = requests.get(dummy_link)
    data = request.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    link = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('var hqurl.*?mp3'))
```

It is returning the whole script tag, but I only want the link assigned to the `hqurl` variable.

Current code with help from @alecxe:

```
request = requests.get('https://www.song365mp3.biz/download/the-beatles-there039s-a-place-studio-outtake-takes-5-amp-6-2788951.html')
    data = request.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    pattern = re.compile("var hqurl = '(.*?mp3)';$", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    link = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
    print(pattern.search(link.text).group(1))
```

But throws error:

```
    print((link.text).group(1))
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: If you're doing a request & then parsing it, the code you have supplied is not the content you want to get the link from.
If you could provide part of the parsed html with the link you require, we would be able to help

Comment: @DNKROZ I fixed it, but the link doesn't matter, as it will always change.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise that the code you posted was where you wanted the link extracted from. I thought it was another response - added an answer which should be what you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-compile the pattern and *reuse* for both locating the element and extracting the link:

```
pattern = re.compile("var hqurl = '(.*?mp3)';", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
link = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
print(pattern.search(link.text).group(1))
```

Note that I've improved the expression and added a capturing group that would save the actual link in a group which we then access via `.group(1)`.

Prints:

```
http://stream1.song365.me/h1/20160129/1772422101/The%20Beatles%20-%20There%27s%20a%20Place%20%28Studio%20Outtake%20Takes%205%20%26%206%29_(song365.cc).mp3
```

Comment: I'm getting:
    `print(pattern.search(link.text).group(1))`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: @ou_snaaksie are you sure you have copied the code as is? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, quite sure

Comment: @ou_snaaksie okay, please edit the question and post your complete code you are currently executing. Cause it works for me on your sample data. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the original post to reflect the changes.

Comment: @ou_snaaksie okay, just remove the `$` from the expression - worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `link = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('var hqurl = (.*?mp3)'))`

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/jX7xK7/1